# How to concatenate two lists of strings based on a shared index, with no spaces

Tags: r, string, slice

I am working in R. Say I have two separate lists:
`a <- ["Cat", "Dog", "Mouse"]`
`b <- ["One", Two", "Three"].`

My desired output would be list c, `["CatOne", "DogTwo", "MouseThree"]`

I know that using a combination of gsub and paste I can accomplish this when dealing with two strings, but I do not know how to accomplish this when dealing with a list of strings. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using `paste0`.

```
paste0(a, b)
# [1] "CatOne"     "DogTwo"     "MouseThree"
```

---

*Data:*

```
a <- list("Cat", "Dog", "Mouse"); b <- list("One", "Two", "Three")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_c` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

str_c(a, b)

# [1] "CatOne"     "DogTwo"     "MouseThree"
```

Or with `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)

stri_paste(a, b)
```

**Data**

```
a <- list("Cat", "Dog", "Mouse")
b <- list("One", "Two", "Three")
```